# how to list all local storage on page properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to show all my localstorage items value on my index page but for some reason it is not showing. can anyone see what I am doing wrong in my code below. In my index page script I am looping thorough the length of local storage and trying to display them on screen, only thing that display is one item. Please help. thanks for your help.

here is my code (index page script):

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        var dataFromLocalStorage = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            dataFromLocalStorage =
                dataFromLocalStorage + " " + localStorage.getItem(`key${i}`);
        }
        document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = dataFromLocalStorage; // Updating same thing
})
```

The other script where I load it to localStorage:

```
var addToTheContent = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var scheduleEvent = document.getElementById("scheduleStartTime");
     var candidateId = document.getElementById('candsId');
     var getCandId = document.getElementById("candsId");

     var displayCandId = candidateId.options[candidateId.selectedIndex].value;

     var id = 1;

     function addTheEvent() {
         var showText = addToTheContent.innerHTML = displayCandId + " ( " + scheduleEvent.value + " ) ";
         localStorage.setItem(`key${id}`, JSON.stringify(showText))
         id += 1
         localStorage.getItem(`key${id}`);
         window.location = "/";
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

"key${id}"  is a template string, you need to use backticks `` instead of quotation marks `""`.

You could also loop through localStorage as you normally would for most JavaScript objects:

```js
for(var key in localStorage) {
  if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // ignore the prototype methods

    // Do whatever you want with key and value found here
    console.log(key + ": " + localStorage[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have done that and now I did with backticks. However, in my index page I am getting a console error: `id is not defined`

Comment: That's probably because you never define id in your index script. You use a for loop with index i, but then you use id in the template string loop block instead of i. `localStorage.getItem(\`key${id}\`);` should be localStorage.getItem(\`key${i+1}\`);`

Comment: I've updated the answer with another process that might make things a little easier. But your methods should work fine once you match up the template string variables.

Answer (score 0):

Typo: Use `i` instead `id`

```
var dataFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem(`key${id}`);
```

correct:

```
var dataFromLocalStorage = `localStorage.getItem("key${i}");
```

Another thing, You are updating same `innerHTML`

```
var dataFromLocalStorage = "";
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  dataFromLocalStorage =
    dataFromLocalStorage + " " + localStorage.getItem(`key${i}`);
}
document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = dataFromLocalStorage; // Updating same thing

// do something with localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
```

// missing template string 'key${id}'

```
var id = 1;
function addTheEvent() {
  var showText = displayCandId + " ( " + scheduleEvent.value + " ) ";
  localStorage.setItem(`key${id}`, JSON.stringify(showText));
  id += 1;
  window.location = "/";
}
```

Comment: I did `localStorage.getItem(`key${i}`);` and it is still showing my first item on the screen rather than all of my keys value. Obviously wrap with a backtick

Comment: So, your update code worked but now in my other script when I add a new value it wont add to my local Storage? did your code break my other script code?

Comment: haha. i m just fetching value.. how it can break code :-D any error ??

Comment: I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` with your updated code

Comment: can u add whole code, updated one.. cant understand what you copy pasted.. Please update you post with latest code at below

Comment: what are u doing in this line ??
`var showText = addToTheContent.innerHTML = displayCandId + " ( " + scheduleEvent.value + " ) ";`

Comment: setting innerHTML and what ??

Comment: DOnet just copy paste, your code has issue. Please check. setting value. Since we can just guide, Debug u have to by own.

Comment: basically that line is grabbing the value from the form and adding it to the index page

Comment: Check code i think mistake is here in `addToTheContent.innerHTML =`

Comment: So, in my index page code script I am getting `keyundefined` in my localstorage

Comment: I dont knw whether you understand my language or not. I have updated my answer. Please check you logic. You logic looks buggy

Comment: I have updated my code.   can you see if its in my addToTheContent.innerHTML again?